# Problem in adding Facebook Like Button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

My URL is something like `www.example.com/product/?mid=1&pid=B0019DVLN2`

If I add this url to the like button it takes only `www.example.com/product/?mid=1` and leaves the rest part of the URL.

I tried using the facebook lint tool. The problem still didnt get solved.

I tried replacing & with & also, but still the problem remains.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to replace & with %26

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this out.. worked fine for me:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fproduct%2F%3Fmid%3D1%26pid%3DB0019DVLN2&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Built link here:
[fbook link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like)